# Views Template Images

Tags: views, theming

I try to make my first views template. I need following for a image gallery based on ZURB Foundation 3 Clearing.

```
<ul class="block-grid three-up" data-clearing>
  <li><a href="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/800"><img data-caption="Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna." src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100"></a></li>
  <li><img data-caption="Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna." src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/800"></li>
  <li><a href="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/800"><img data-caption="Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna." src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100"></a></li>
  <li><img data-caption="Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna." src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/800"></li>
  <li><a href="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/800"><img data-caption="Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna." src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100"></a></li>
  <li><img data-caption="Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna." src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/800"></li>
</ul>
```

I created a view with list `<li>` in Drupal 7 but i need the HTML structure above. At the moment i have only the result with normal `<li><img src="" /></li>` Image Display.

The machine name is "gallery". I know how i can create views, override the template but the problem is, i don't know the PHP Variables for this.

I need the tags data-caption="Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna." and to format the html list like the example above.

For more information about this: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/clearing.php#clearingCode

Comment: is `data-caption` is always different?

Comment: Yes, that is only the title of image. I think it is the best to load mini thumbnails at first, like the Page Speed and on click we load the big image.